# How can I split my form inputs into two columns?

Tags: html, css

As you can see, there are 6 input boxes. I want to know how to divide them into two groups: 3 to the left and 3 to the right.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body ::-moz-placeholder {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 300;
}
body :-ms-input-placeholder {

  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.wrapper {
  background: dimgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

.wrapper.form-success .container h1 {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(85px);
          transform: translateY(85px);
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
  height: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

form {
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

form input {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.25s;
          transition-duration: 0.25s;
  font-weight: 300;
}
form input:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
}
form input:focus {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  color: #807e80;
}
form button {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #3a3c3d;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 250px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}
form button:hover {
  background-color: #f5f7f9;
}

@-webkit-keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
@keyframes square {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
            transform: translateY(-700px) rotate(600deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>        
        <form class="form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name">
            <input type="contact" placeholder="contact number">
            <input type="add" placeholder="Country">
            <input type="Bday" placeholder="Birthday">
            <input type="Age" placeholder="Age">
            <input type="pin" placeholder="Pin number">
            <button type="submit" id="sign">Sign-up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbhishekSoni If you don't think the question is on-topic then you shouldn't have provided an answer.

Comment: @TylerH Where have I stated that the question is off-topic?

Comment: @AbhishekSoni In a now-deleted comment from 2016.

Comment: @TylerH Hence "deleted" ?!

Comment: @AbhishekSoni It was only deleted recently, by a moderator, after I flagged it as unwelcoming. Otherwise I wouldn't have been able to see it to reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? Just a simple solution.

```
    <form class="form" method='post'>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <input type="text" name='name' placeholder="name">
        <input type="tel" name='contact' placeholder="contact number">
        <input type="text" name='country' placeholder="Country">
    </div>
     <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
        <input type="date" name='bday' placeholder="Birthday">
        <input type="number" name='age' placeholder="Age">
        <input type="number" name='pin' placeholder="Pin number">
     </div>   
        <button type="submit" id="sign">Sign-up</button> 
    </form>
```

I've changed the input types to valid types. You gave pin, bday etc which are not valid. You can go through this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) for more information about this.

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML to use Tables:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="body register.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>        
        <form class="form">
          <table>
            <tr><td><input type="text" placeholder="name"></td>
            <td><input type="contact" placeholder="contact number"></td>


            </tr>
            <tr><td><input type="add" placeholder="Country"></td>
            <td><input type="Bday" placeholder="Birthday"></td>


            </tr>
          <tr>

            <td><input type="Age" placeholder="Age"></td>
            <td>
            <input type="pin" placeholder="Pin number"></td>


           </tr>
           </table>
            <button type="submit" id="sign">Sign-up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

See this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGJVeJ?editors=110)

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution using flexbox, as in the future you may have to add more inputs as well as serve it over a range of devices.

You can change the submit button as required.

```css
.form{
display:flex;
border:1px solid black;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content:space-between;

}

.form > *{
flex:1;
flex-basis:33.33%;
}

 input{
   
   display:block;
   
 }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>        
        <form class="form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="name"> 
            <input type="contact" placeholder="contact number">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Country">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Birthday">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Age">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Pin number">
            <button type="submit" id="sign">Sign-up</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```